# Replace string in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array in javascript. This array has strings that contains commas (","). I want all commas to be removed from this array. Can this be done?

Comment: Can't you filter the strings before them being pushed in the array? Otherwise is just a simple for loop.

Comment: I tried to but the strings are coming from other place, dynamically. But it doesn't matter anyway, I figured out what I was doing wrong. I was leaving a comma after every db result. I was convinced that the array push I was doing was adding a comma after every push. I'm a starter in JS. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Yes.

```
for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/,/g, '');
}
```

Comment: +1 for getting closer than me but you need to do something with the result, replace does not mutate the string.

Comment: Sorry kekoav, 

Shoudn't it be:

arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/,/g, '');

??

Answer (score 39):

The best way nowadays is to use the `map()` function in this way:

```
var resultArr = arr.map(function(x){return x.replace(/,/g, '');});
```

this is ECMA-262 standard.
If you nee it for earlier version you can add this piece of code in your project:

```
if (!Array.prototype.map)
{
    Array.prototype.map = function(fun /*, thisp*/)
    {
        var len = this.length;
        if (typeof fun != "function")
          throw new TypeError();

        var res = new Array(len);
        var thisp = arguments[1];
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            if (i in this)
                res[i] = fun.call(thisp, this[i], i, this);
        }

        return res;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 14):

you can also do it inline in a shorter syntax

```
array = array.map(x => x.replace(/,/g,""));
```

Answer (score 10):

You can simply do:

```
array = ["erf,","erfeer,rf","erfer"];
array = array.map(function(x){ return x.replace(/,/g,"") });
```

Now Array Becomes:

`["erf", "erfeerrf", "erfer"]`

Comment: You do not need to (read: should not) test the regex yourself, that happens under the hood anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Sure -- just iterate through the array and do a standard removal on each iteration.

Or if the nature of your array permits, you could first convert the array to a string, take out the commas, then convert back into an array.