# function for manually order string

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I'm trying to learn how functions work in JS.
This function should order the string, but the result is equal to the string himself.
what do I do wrong?

```js
a = "awbc"

function f(str) {
  let temporary
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
      if (a[j] < a[j + 1]) {
        temporary = a[j]
        a[j] = a[j + 1]
        a[j + 1] = temporary

      }

    }

  }
  return a
}

console.log(f(a))
```

Comment: Strings are immutable; you cannot change them as if they were arrays. You can instead turn a string into an array, sort it (probably with `.sort()` instead of a home-made function) and then join the array back into a string.

Comment: wanted to answer with the same content)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a replace method on array values. See this for reference:
[Replace string in javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953311/replace-string-in-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0):

#### Strings are immutable

As already pointed out by [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy) (*edit*: believe it or not, no pun intended) in the comments, strings are immutable and cannot be changed. But what you can do is create one separate string for each character in your string and put that in an array using the [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method. Then you can sort that array and when it is sorted use [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to create another string consisting of those characters in sorted order.

#### Your `bubbleSort()` implementation

First of all the algorithm you are trying to implement is called [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) and is one of the easy but unfortunately slow sorting algorithms as it takes `O(n²)` in best, average and worst case runtime while good algorithms like [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) only take `O(n * log n)`.

Nevertheless, if you want to sort using `bubbleSort()` you need to make some changes to your code.
You are sorting in **descending** order therefore in every iteration of the outer loop the biggest value will be moved to the left-most position. Therefore in the next iteration you need to find the next biggest value and move it to the now left-most position. No need to check for all elements again as we already know that the left-most element is the biggest. Therefore start your inner loop at position `i` instead of `0`. This will change nothing in the time complexity in big-O notation but will nevertheless improve the performance significantly.

| Iteration i of outer loop | temporary |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | [ a,w,b,c ] |
| 1 | [ w,b,c,a ] |
| 2 | [ w,c,b,a ] |
| 3 | [ w,c,b,a ] |

Also you are using a function in order to encapsulate functionality so you should not modify global variables within it. Use the `str` parameter you pass to it instead of `a`.

Last but not least you have this line `temporary = a[j]` but `temporary` should hold your array of individual character strings which you will destroy with this assignment. Create a new variable `temp` instead to do the swap.

Here an implementation of `bubbleSort()` with all those issues addressed.

```js
/**
 * Bubble sort algorithm which has sorts characters in a string in descending order.
 * Best/ average and worst case runtime of bubble sort is O(n²).
 * As we iterate n times over (n - i) items.
 * T(n) = Sum{from 0 to n}[n * (n-i)] = (n + 1) * n =  n² + n = O(n²)
 * @param {string} str string
 * @returns 
 */
function bubbleSort(str) {
  const temporary = str.split("");
  // temporary now contains every single character
  console.log("After split:", temporary);
  // in each iteration of the outer loop the "biggest" letter will be sorted to the front
  for (let i = 0; i < temporary.length; i++) {
    // you need to start from i as otherwise you will be moving already sorted letters (as they are moved to the front)
    for (let j = i; j < temporary.length - 1; j++) {
      if (temporary[j] < temporary[j + 1]) {
        // you need other variable here, otherwise you will override temporary
        const temp = temporary[j];
        temporary[j] = temporary[j + 1];
        temporary[j + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  // now join characters back together to a string
  console.log("After sorting: ", temporary);
  return temporary.join("");
}

console.log(bubbleSort("awbc"));
console.log(bubbleSort("another _string with &)8 w?ird chars"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```