# How do I remove all occurrences of a particular text from an array of strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This code's goal is to take a multi-line string input (from a single cell in Google Sheets) and break it into pieces to the point where math operations can be performed for a total run mileage figure as the end result.

Example multi-line string input:

```js
"2.5mi warmup
100met sprint
200met slow
repeat 4x
2mi tempo
1mi slow
repeat 8x
1mi jog
200met walk
repeat 4x
5mi cooldown"
```

After filtering out the first and last lines and then performing a split function using /x/ as the regex, I have the following array:

```js
//arraysplitrepeatblocks = 
[ '  \n100met sprint \n200met slow \nrepeat 4',
  ' \n2mi tempo \n1mi slow \nrepeat 8',
  ' \n1mi jog \n200met walk \nrepeat 4',
  ' \n ' ]
```

I am trying to clean up this data by removing any mentions of "\n" from each string within the array. I tried the code below but it is not an accepted function (I'm assuming due to the object being an array instead of a string; perhaps some iteration is necessary).

```js
let arraycleanedup = arraysplitrepeatblocks.replace(/\s+\\n/,"");

//Error given:
TypeError: arraysplitrepeatblocks.replace is not a function
```

Expected result:

```js
[ ' 100met sprint 200met slow repeat 4',
  ' 2mi tempo 1mi slow repeat 8',
  ' 1mi jog 200met walk repeat 4',
  ' ' ]
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Also, is there a way to delete that final empty array element? If so, the expected result after that operation would be:

```js
[ ' 100met sprint 200met slow repeat 4',
  ' 2mi tempo 1mi slow repeat 8',
  ' 1mi jog 200met walk repeat 4']
```

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: My fault. I am working in Javascript. Updated title.

Comment: `replace` is indeed [not a function on arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).  Did you mean to loop over the array and call `replace` on each string?

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.map()` to perform the same replacement on each element of the array.

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.pop()` to remove the last element of the array.

Comment: @David Yes. Essentially I want to use a regex (/\s+\\n/g) to replace all occurrences of "\n" with a space. And I want this to apply to all elements within the array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace string in javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953311/replace-string-in-javascript-array)

Comment: That final element isn't empty, but you can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove any array elements you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = [
  '  \n100m sprint \n200m slow \nrepeat 4',
  ' \n2mi tempo \n1mi slow \nrepeat 8',
  ' \n1mi jog \n200m walk \nrepeat 4',
  ' \n '
].reduce((acc, string) => {
  const formattedStr = string.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); // Remove leading and trailing whitespaces
  if (formattedStr !== '') {
    acc.push(formattedStr);
  }
  return acc; // Return the accumulator in each iteration
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Try testing if `/^\s+|\s+$|\n/g` matches the new line within `formattedStr` to be removed?